# How can I control the order of attributes when converting dataclasses to a dict in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, attributes, python-dataclasses

i want to used named data in my project but in the end i have to convert the data to a CSV file.

My approach is to use list of dataclasses in the code as data containers. In the end the list of dataclasses is converted to a list of dicts and from that to a CSV file.

I want to control the order in which the attributes appear in the final data object. Here is my code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyClass:
    c: str
    b: str
    a: str = "Default"

objdata = [
    MyClass(c="Foo", b="Bar"),
    MyClass(c="Test", b="Test"),
    MyClass(c="asdf", b="yxcv")
    ]

dictdata = []
attributes = [a for a in dir(objdata[0]) if not a.startswith('__')]
for entry in objdata:
    csv_entry = {}
    for attribute in attributes:
        csv_entry[attribute] = getattr(entry, attribute)
    dictdata.append(csv_entry)
```

I have several dataclasses with different attributes. I want to reuse the code converting the dataclass to a dict, so i loop over the attributes in the class. The problem is dir returns the attributes in alphabetical order (so a, b c) and not in the order i declared them in the class (which is c, b, a). Is there a way to control this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you should just use `dataclasses.asdict`, which implements this behavior for any object that is an instance of a class created by a class that was decorated with the `dataclasses.dataclass` code generator.

```
>>> import dataclasses
>>> @dataclasses.dataclass
... class MyClass:
...     c: str
...     b: str
...     a: str = "Default"
...
>>> objdata = [
...     MyClass(c="Foo", b="Bar"),
...     MyClass(c="Test", b="Test"),
...     MyClass(c="asdf", b="yxcv")
...     ]
>>>
>>> for obj in objdata:
...     print(dataclasses.asdict(obj))
...
{'c': 'Foo', 'b': 'Bar', 'a': 'Default'}
{'c': 'Test', 'b': 'Test', 'a': 'Default'}
{'c': 'asdf', 'b': 'yxcv', 'a': 'Default'}
```

Note, this is implemented by using `dataclasses.fields(obj)`, which ultimately just access the `__dataclass_fields__` class variable. The details are all pretty easy to follow in the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/aca77b5530c34fb2ada0fe02fb83f4c9fa9256f3/Lib/dataclasses.py#L1263)

Note, if you simply wanted to write every object that you know is of some specific dataclass type to a csv, I wouldn't create intermediate dicts. You could just do:

```
import operator
import csv

fields = [f.name for f in dataclasses.fields(MyClass)]
getter_func = operator.attrgetter(*fields)

with open("data.csv") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(fields) # If you want a header
    writer.writerows(map(getter_func, objdata))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.11.3 the attributes can be acquired in order of declaration thus:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class A:
    c: str
    b: str
    a: str

a = A(a='A', c='C', b='B')

for key in a.__dict__:
    print(key)
```

**Output:**

```
c
b
a
```